# svn import error : Could not write svndiff to temp file: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: svn

I have some repositories integrated with apache. While importing small projects it works fine. But when i import somewhat huge project say about 2GB of size, I get the following error. I use tortoise svn.

`Could not write svndiff to temp file: There is not enough space on the disk.`

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have enough space on a disk where your tmp dir is located?

Comment: I have some 60 GB for the svn root ie, /var/www/svn. Of which only half a GB has been used now.

Comment: And what about temporary dir?

Comment: troubling to find the temp file. There's nothing in subversion.conf, related to this.

Comment: @itsraja: **temporary directory** not file

Comment: @itsraja: omg........ **YOUR OPERATING SYSTEM TEMPORARY DIRECTORY**

Comment: sorry, I was searching in svn's. I haven't set anything as temporary directory, it seems. When echoed $TMPDIR, it is empty.

Comment: I believe it uses /tmp directory and it has enough space. should I set something using env var.

Comment: I set TMPDIR, and the issue fixed, thanks zerkms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: the OP [itsraja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552423/itsraja)  finally found the $TMPDIR environment variable wasn't set (after some advices from [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) in the comments above)

> Sorry, I was searching in SVN's.
>   I haven't set anything as temporary directory, it seems. When echoed `$TMPDIR`, it is empty.
>   I believe it uses `/tmp` directory and it has enough space.
>   **I set `$TMPDIR`, and the issue fixed, thanks**

---

Initial answer:

According to [this post](http://softwarealchemist.net/2010/05/subversion-not-enough-space-on-the-disk/) (for a Windows client, but the idea is still valid for an Unix client):

> Using Subversion (via Tortoise, incidentally), I recently got this error:

```
svn:

Can't set position pointer in file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\report.tmp':

There is not enough space on the disk.
```

> This means you have **run out of space on your server**.
>   Sounds straight forward, but it took a while fooling around on the client

It could be a similar problem in your case (if you do have space left locally).

---

Or it could be an ACL (access rights) issue on the `tmp` directory as [described here](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2007-08/0607.shtml):

> Subversion uses an APR function (which we donated to that project) for finding a temporary directory.
>   It does so by trying to find a writable directory using the following search path:

```
      $TMP
      $TEMP
      $TMPDIR
      "C:\TEMP" (windows only)
      "SYS:\TMP" (netware only)
      "/tmp"
      "/var/tmp"
      "/usr/tmp"
      P_tmpdir (POSIX define)
      `pwd`
```

> Do you have one of those first three environment variables set to a non-writable location?

Answer (score 0):

We ran across this issue and the problem was not with space on the subversion server - rather the client's desktop.  If you have folks using workstation side software, check it for space too.

Answer (score 0):

Same error observed today on multiple clients. Turns out the svn server was out of space. Apparently the tmp file error had originated from the server. Solution: free up disk space on the server and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by an overly large commit.  Try committing fewer files.

Answer (score 0):

Like many other users, I also faced this issue. I was getting below mentioned error

```
Can't write to file 'C:\Windows\TEMP\tempfile.199.tmp'
```

The above-mentioned file was missing in the folder. I Fixed the issue by creating an empty file with the above-mentioned name in     C:\Windows\TEMP location.